# iPhone App failed to install

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

Through the safari browser , I have added one of my org device UDID in the Developer account. Now I am trying to install one of custom application using iTunes to that device. But App failed to install.

I am able to see in the Developer account that , under the profiles , it is showing 0.
Why I am unable to install the app in the device.

The same scenario I tried with iPad , But It got installed. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason ??

Comment: Did you update the developer provisioning profile with the newly added device?

Comment: after adding new UDID to the Ad Hoc profile for distribution you need to again download provision profile and by double tapping on it to install in the Xcode or please check the UDID is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is sign the Application with an Adhoc_Distribution Profile and include your iPhone as well as any other devices you want to deploy your application on.

To create the profile, go to provisioning portal, select Provisioning from left, then choose distribution tab. From there select Adhoc_Distribution, select proper AppID and add the devices you want to deploy application upon.

Download the profile and follow these steps..

http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

Then use the iTunes to install the Application on required devices.

Comment: I have removed one of the iPad from the registered devices from the developer account and I have connected to a new pc. Now I tried to install the same application using iTunes in that iPad. It got installed. How come ?

Comment: because you are using the old archive signed with distribution profile that contained the UDID of the iPad. If you re-create distribution profile with iPad removed and then create the archive with new profile, it won't get installed on iPad.